# AnkiTools : TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() when using anki_convert

Tags: python, xlsx, anki

I'm trying to convert an excel of a deck to apkg:

```
anki_convert(in_file='deck.xlsx', out_format='.apkg')
```

But the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I tried it with many different files with different values but still the same error.
Any thoughts on how to solve it?

Edit: Full error trace-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/###/anki/edit_deck.py", line 57, in <module>
anki_convert(in_file='deck.xlsx', out_format='.apkg')
File "C:\Users\###\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\AnkiTools\editor.py", line 83, in anki_convert
AnkiFormatEditor().convert(in_file, out_file, out_format)
File "C:\Users\###\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\AnkiTools\editor.py", line 49, in convert
self.zip(self.import_anki_sqlite(in_file), out_file)
File "C:\Users\###\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\AnkiTools\editor.py", line 77, in import_anki_sqlite
sync_portal.to_sqlite()
File "C:\Users\###\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\AnkiTools\excel\app.py", line 190, in to_sqlite
self.anki_direct.add(self.to_payload())
File "C:\Users\###\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\AnkiTools\api\ankidirect.py", line 135, in add
modified=modified)
File "C:\Users\###\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\AnkiTools\tools\create.py", line 144, in new_note
sfld = BeautifulSoup(flds_list[0], 'html.parser').text
File "C:\Users\###\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 287, in __init__
elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: Can you share a full error trace, please?